# Remove duplicates based on criteria in multiple columns across two data frames

Tags: r, duplicates

I have 2 data frames that I need to compare to remove duplicates. DF1 has columns A, B, C, D, E, F, and DF2 has columns A, B, C, G, H, I. 
I want to get all rows from DF1 where either column A or B matches either column A or B from DF2 AND DF2 column G is not "Y"

So something along the lines of

```
DF3 <- subset (DF1, (A | B %in% DF2$A | DF2$B) & (C %in% DF2$C) & (DF2$G != "Y"))
```

But I cant get the logical operators to work within the subset. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want that [DF1$A match DF2$A or DF1$B match DF2$B] OR [DF1$A match (DF2$A or DF2$B) or DF1$B match (DF2$A or DF2$B)]?

Comment: Instead of (A | B %in% ...), try (A %in% DF2$A | B %in%DF2$A ..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using an inner join with sqldf

Example data . Please provide this yourself in the future.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 1:10, c = 1:10, g = tail(letters, 10))
set.seed(2019)
df2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(df1, function(x) sample(x, replace = TRUE)))
```

Inner join and output:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("
select  a.*
from    df1 a
        join df2 b      
          on  (a.a = b.a or a.b = b.b)
              and a.c = b.c
where   b.g <> 'y'
")

#   a b c g
# 1 2 2 2 r
# 2 1 1 1 q
# 3 5 5 5 u
```